# USB Drive that mirrors PC drive via WiFi

Tags: wifi, data-storage

I've got a small device that reads data off of a thumbdrive. I'd rather not be carrying my thumbdrive back and forth. I thought I remembered a USB drive out there that would connect to your WiFi network and act like a mirror for some folder on your desktop.

Is this a real thing?

Edit: Here's what I want:

```
[Device] ---USB--> [Thing] ---WiFi-->--Network--> [Desktop]
```

Specifically I want `[Thing]`

Comment: https://www.amazon.com/SanDisk-Connect-Wireless-Stick-Flash/dp/B00ZCFYT5K

Like this?

Comment: No this goes the wrong direction. Updated question to clarify.

Comment: You could set up a server (for example using a raspberry pi or something like that) and connect your USB to it. This would act like dropbox. Own Cloud (https://owncloud.org/) is an open source software for that.